# Do animals "live, reside or inhabit" in a place?

Tags: grammar

I am working on a standardized test, where one of the questions asks whether a certain type of animals live/reside/inhabit in Alaska. To me they all sound okay. But the answer key marks "live" as the correct answer. Any idea?

Comment: Contrary to most of the comments below, 'reside' is perfectly acceptable--but only in certain contexts, for example when the focus is on particular time and place.  "Migrating terns only reside in Alaska from May to July, for the rest of the year etc."

Answer (score 6):

*Inhabit* is quite obviously wrong, because you inhabit a place—you cannot inhabit *in* a place.

*Reside* implies having a residence (i.e., a house or something like it) and living there permanently or for a long time. It sounds odd to say an animal resides somewhere, especially when the somewhere is a vast place like Alaska. A residence is a more narrowly defined area: you wouldn't likely say of a person that they reside in Alaska, either, though you might say that they reside in Juneau, and definitely that they reside in 1773 Park Drive, Juneau. (Assuming that address exists, which it probably doesn't.)

Comment: To be clear, saying "an animal inhabits Alaska" is perfectly fine, isn't it, and you prefer the verb _live_ to _inhabit_ here because of the preposition _in_?

Comment: I find “wolves have long inhabited the northern parts if Alaska” perfectly natural, but “wolves inhabit Alaska” still sounds somehow ‘off’ somehow, though I can't quite explain why.

Comment: I agree. That's because using the simple present sounds weird here. "Wolves live in Alaska" also sounds off to me, but that's perhaps because we know they inhabit other regions of the planet as well. Take a look at the example sentences here: [inhabit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inhabit?q=inhabit).

Answer (score 2):

"**Live**," "**inhabit**," and "[**reside**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humans+reside+in%2Canimals+reside+in%2Cmen+reside+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumans%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimals%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0)" all are appropriate options, "live" being the most common one, though, for [**animals**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=animals+live+in%2Canimals+reside+in%2Canimals+inhabit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canimals%20live%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimals%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimals%20inhabit%3B%2Cc0)...and [**humans**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humans+reside+in%2Cmen+reside+in%2Chumans+resided+in%2Cmen+resided+in%2Chumans+live+in%2Cmen+live+in%2Chumans+lived+in%2Cmen+lived+in%2Chumans+inhabit%2Cmen+inhabit%2Chumans+inhabited%2Cmen+inhabited&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumans%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20resided%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20live%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20live%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20lived%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20lived%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20inhabit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20inhabit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20inhabited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20inhabited%3B%2Cc0) alike.

Alternately, you can add "**dwell**" and "**populate**" to that list.

> [**inhabit**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inhabit): to live or dwell in a place, as people or animals; e.g. *The grizzly bear inhabits Alaska*.
>
> [**reside**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reside): to live **in a particular place**; to be present **in a particular place**; e.g. *A quarter of the current Steller sea lion population [**resides**](http://www.gi.alaska.edu/node/494) in Alaska*; *Most of our brown bear population [**resides**](http://princeofwalesonline.com/?p=9) in Alaska*; *The wolverine also [**resides**](http://www.nwf.org/wildlife/wildlife-library/mammals/wolverine.aspx) in Alaska, Canada, and Russia, where it is not emperiled*.
>
> [**dwell**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dwell): to inhabit or live in; be an inhabitant of; e.g. *This kind of fish dwells near the bottom of the ocean*; *Polar bears dwell in northern and western Alaska*.
>
> [**populate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/populate): to live in; inhabit; e.g. *Creatures that populate the ocean depths*; *Brown bears [populate](http://www.southeastalaskabnbs.com/Hyder.html) the ALaska landscape from the bottom of the Southeast panhandle from Hyder north to Yakutat*.

Answer (score 0):

I think **live** is the best choice. Also according to [Ngran](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=animals%20live,animals%20reside,%20animals%20inhabit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,animals%20live;,c0;.t1;,animals%20reside;,c0;.t1;,animals%20inhabit;,c0) *live* is the verb most used referring to animals.

Comment: Apparently, it is not specific to animals. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humans+live+in%2Chumans+reside+in%2Chumans+inhabit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumans%20live%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20reside%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%20inhabit%3B%2Cc0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the word "in" is required, that knocks out "inhabit" as an option.

"Reside in" also sounds funny but that isn't the real problem.  *Reside* implies legal residence.  A bear might "live" in Alaska, but if it were to "reside" there, I would expect it to vote in Alaska elections, pay taxes, and sit on juries.

Answer (score 0):

**Reside**

I don't like this for animals.  I reside in [town name] or in the [name] apartment complex.  It is a fixed community.  Not many animals have this sort of situation.  I am not saying it could never happen but far less.

> Usage:  The cats reside on the 3rd floor of the pet shop.

_

---

_

**Inhabits**

Good word for describing animals location but it seems much much better when used in the past tense.  Also tends to work better for animal groups rather than a single animal.

> Usage: Dinosaurs inhabited Earth 100 million years ago.
>
> Weird usage: The geese inhabit Lake Michigan.
>
> Another Weird usage: There was a dinosaur named Tom that inhabited what is now Minnesota.

_

---

_

**Live**

Probably the easiest word to use when describing animals in general.  Not many cases where it doesn't work, yet doesn't sound as scientific as inhabited.

> Usage: There was a dinosaur named Tom that lived in what is now
>   Minnesota.
>
> Usage: The geese live in Lake Michigan.